# Issue with d3 chart cross hair, when zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

Im using d3 line chart and created cross hair with value on it.
Facing issue when zoom in.
Cross hair not updated with new zoomed value. its have the old value and shows the value as first.
How do i fix this, and make cross hair with zoomed values

Here is my code:

```
var self = this;
    this.margin = { top: 0, right: 45, bottom: 20, left: 0 };
    this.size = {
        width: $('#realtimechart').width() - 40,
        height: 300
    };

    $('#realtimechart').empty();

    this.x = d3.time.scale.utc()
        .domain(d3.extent(self.plots, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }))
        .range([0, this.size.width])
        .clamp(true);

    this.y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(self.plots, function (d) {
            return d.close;
        })])
        .range([this.size.height, 0])
        .clamp(true);

    this.line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return self.x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return self.y(d.close);
        });

    this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.x).ticks(12).orient('bottom');
    this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.y).ticks(8).orient('right');

    this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(this.x).scaleExtent([1,10]).on('zoom', this.redraw());
    this.zoom.scale(currentZoom).translate([0, 0]);

    this.svg = d3.select('#realtimechart').append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.size.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr('height', this.size.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')')
        .call(this.zoom);
    this.makeX = function () {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(self.x)
            .orient('bottom')
            .ticks(12);
    };

    this.makeY = function () {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(self.y)
            .orient('left')
            .ticks(8);
    };

    this.svg.append('rect')
        .attr('width', this.size.width)
        .attr('height', this.size.height);


    var focus = this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","focus")
        .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("line")
        .attr({
            "x1": -this.size.width,
            "y1": 0,
            "x2": this.size.width,
            "y2": 0
        });

    focus.append("line")
        .attr({
            "x1": 0,
            "y1": -this.size.height,
            "x2": 0,
            "y2": this.size.height
        });

    var tipValue = this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","focus")
        .style("display", "none");

    tipValue.append("text")
        .attr("x", -10);

    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
    var formatValue = d3.format(",.2f");
    var formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };
    var xDomain = d3.extent(self.chartData, function (d, i){ return d.date; });
    var yMin = d3.min(self.chartData, function(d){ return Math.min(d.close); });
    var yMax = d3.max(self.chartData, function(d){ return Math.max(d.close); });
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, this.size.width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([this.size.height, 0]);
    x.domain([self.chartData[0].date, self.chartData[self.chartData.length - 1].date]);
    y.domain(d3.extent(self.chartData, function(d) { return d.close; }));

    function mousemove() {
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(self.chartData, x0, 1),
        d0 = self.chartData[i - 1],
        d1 = self.chartData[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

        focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
        tipValue.attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)");
        tipValue.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
    }

    this.svg.on('mouseover', function() {
        focus.style("display", null);
        tipValue.style("display", null);
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
        tipValue.style("display", "none");
    }).on('mousemove', mousemove);        


    this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.size.height + ')')
        .call(this.xAxis);

    this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.size.width + ', 0)')
        .call(this.yAxis);

    this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x grid')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.size.height + ')')
        .call(this.makeX()
        .tickSize(-this.size.height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(''));

    this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y grid')
        .call(this.makeY()
        .tickSize(-this.size.width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(''));

    this.clip = this.svg.append('svg:clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip')
      .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', this.size.width)
        .attr('height', this.size.height);

    this.chartBody = this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
      .append('svg:path')
        .datum(self.plots)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', this.line);
}

Chart.prototype.redraw = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        currentZoom = d3.event.scale;
        self.svg.select('.x.axis').call(self.xAxis);
        self.svg.select('.y.axis').call(self.yAxis);
        self.svg.select('.x.grid')
            .call(self.makeX()
            .tickSize(-self.size.height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(''));
        self.svg.select('.y.grid')
            .call(self.makeY()
            .tickSize(-self.size.width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(''));
        self.svg.select('.line')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('d', self.line);
    };
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: thanks Oleg, i have update my question, with code